# How do I get a summary count of missing/NaN data by column in 'pandas'?

Tags: pandas, reporting, nan, missing-data

In *R* I can quickly see a count of missing data using the `summary` command, but the equivalent `pandas` DataFrame method, `describe` does not report these values.

I gather I can do something like

```
len(mydata.index) - mydata.count()
```

to compute the number of missing values for each column, but I wonder if there's a better idiom (or if my approach is even right).

Comment: Similar question for rows: [Python/Pandas: counting the number of missing/NaN in each row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059260/python-pandas-counting-the-number-of-nan-in-each-row)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Both `describe` and `info` report the count of non-missing values.

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2))

In [2]: df.iloc[3:6,0] = np.nan

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
          0         1
0 -0.560342  1.862640
1 -1.237742  0.596384
2  0.603539 -1.561594
3       NaN  3.018954
4       NaN -0.046759
5       NaN  0.480158
6  0.113200 -0.911159
7  0.990895  0.612990
8  0.668534 -0.701769
9 -0.607247 -0.489427

[10 rows x 2 columns]

In [4]: df.describe()
Out[4]: 
              0          1
count  7.000000  10.000000
mean  -0.004166   0.286042
std    0.818586   1.363422
min   -1.237742  -1.561594
25%   -0.583795  -0.648684
50%    0.113200   0.216699
75%    0.636036   0.608839
max    0.990895   3.018954

[8 rows x 2 columns]


In [5]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 2 columns):
0    7 non-null float64
1    10 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
```

To get a count of missing, your soln is correct

```
In [20]: len(df.index)-df.count()
Out[20]: 
0    3
1    0
dtype: int64
```

You could do this too

```
In [23]: df.isnull().sum()
Out[23]: 
0    3
1    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 12):

As a tiny addition, to get percentage missing by DataFrame column, combining @Jeff and @userS's answers above gets you:

```
100*(df.isnull().sum())/len(df)
```

Answer (score 8):

Following one will do the trick and will return counts of nulls for every column:

`df.isnull().sum(axis=0)`

`df.isnull()` returns a dataframe with True / False values

`sum(axis=0)` sums the values across all rows for a column

Answer (score 3):

This isnt quite a full summary, but it will give you a quick sense of your column level data

```
def getPctMissing(series):
    num = series.isnull().sum()
    den = series.count()
    return 100*(num/den)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see not null summary of each column , just use `df.info(null_counts=True)`:

Example 1:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,5), columns=list('abcde'))
df.iloc[:4,0] = np.nan
df.iloc[:3,1] = np.nan
df.iloc[:2,2] = np.nan
df.iloc[:1,3] = np.nan

df.info(null_counts=True)
```

output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   a       6 non-null      float64
 1   b       7 non-null      float64
 2   c       8 non-null      float64
 3   d       9 non-null      float64
 4   e       10 non-null     float64
dtypes: float64(5)
memory usage: 528.0 bytes
```

In addition, if you want to customize the result , such as add nan_rate , I wrote a method

```
def describe_nan(df):
    return pd.DataFrame([(i, df[df[i].isna()].shape[0],df[df[i].isna()].shape[0]/df.shape[0]) for i in df.columns], columns=['column', 'nan_counts', 'nan_rate'])

describe_nan(df)

>>> column  nan_counts  nan_rate
0   a   4   0.4
1   b   3   0.3
2   c   2   0.2
3   d   1   0.1
4   e   0   0.0
```

Comment: `null_counts` is deprecated now

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't care which columns had Nan's and you just wanted to check overall, just add a second .sum() to get a single value.

```
result = df.isnull().sum().sum()
result > 0
```

a Series would only need one .sum() and a Panel() would need three

Answer (score 1):

This is code makes your life easy

`import sidetable`

`df.stb.missing()`

Check this out : https://github.com/chris1610/sidetable

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to process numerous large datasets to get NaNs information (counts and portions per column) and timing was an issue. So I timed various methods for getting summary counts of NaNs per column in a separate dataframe with column names, NaN counts and NaN portions as columns:

```py
# create random dataframe
dfa = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100000,300))
# add 30% random NaNs
dfa = dfa.mask(np.random.random(dfa.shape) < 0.3)
```

With **pandas methods only**:

```py
%%timeit
nans_dfa = dfa.isna().sum().rename_axis('Columns').reset_index(name='Counts')
nans_dfa["NaNportions"] = nans_dfa["Counts"] / dfa.shape[0]

# Output:
# 10 loops, best of 5: 57.8 ms per loop
```

Using **list comprehension**, based on the fine [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67411199/10074873) from @Mithril:

```py
%%timeit
nan_dfa_loop2 = pd.DataFrame([(col, dfa[dfa[col].isna()].shape[0], dfa[dfa[col].isna()].shape[0]/dfa.shape[0]) for col in dfa.columns], columns=('Columns', 'Counts', 'NaNportions'))

# Output:
# 1 loop, best of 5: 13.9 s per loop
```

Using **list comprehension with a second for loop** to store the result of method calls to reduce calls to these methods:

```py
%%timeit
nan_dfa_loop1 = pd.DataFrame([(col, n, n/dfa.shape[0]) for col in dfa.columns for n in (dfa[col].isna().sum(),) if n], columns=('Columns', 'Counts', 'NaNportions'))

# Output:
# 1 loop, best of 5: 373 ms per loop
```

All the above will produce the same dataframe:

```
    Columns Counts  NaNportions
0   0   29902   0.29902
1   1   30101   0.30101
2   2   30008   0.30008
3   3   30194   0.30194
4   4   29856   0.29856
... ... ... ...
295 295 29823   0.29823
296 296 29818   0.29818
297 297 29979   0.29979
298 298 30050   0.30050
299 299 30192   0.30192
```

('Columns' is redundant with this test dataframe. It is just used as placeholder where in a real life dataset it would probably represent the names of the attributes in the initial dataframe.)

Answer (score 0):

**More precise one:**

```
missed_values = df.isnull()

for col in missed_values.columns.values.tolist():

   if True in missed_values[col].values:
       print(missed_values[col].name, missed_values[col].value_counts())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check what of the columns have missing values, you can go for:

```
mydata.isna().any()
```

Which will print a True in case the column have any missing value

```
col1  False
col2  False
col3  True
```

If you want the count of missing values, then you can type:

```
mydata.isna().sum()
```

Which will print the number of rows with missing value for each column

```
col1  0
col2  0
col3  5
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend using the missingno package (https://github.com/ResidentMario/missingno), which allows you to quickly and easily visualize missing data from a pandas dataframe. My preferred visualization is a bar chart, but they have others.

```
import missingno as msno
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('some_data.csv')

msno.bar(df.sample(1000))
```