# How to check if any value is NaN in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

How do I check whether a pandas DataFrame has NaN values?

I know about `pd.isnan` but it returns a DataFrame of booleans. I also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754891/python-nan-value-in-pandas) but it doesn't exactly answer my question either.

Comment: check out [summary of the counts of missing data in pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257527/how-do-i-get-a-summary-of-the-counts-of-missing-data-in-pandas)

Comment: Best answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257527/how-do-i-get-a-summary-count-of-missing-nan-data-by-column-in-pandas/75632616#75632616

Answer (score 852, accepted):

[jwilner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1567452/jwilner)'s response is spot on. I was exploring to see if there's a faster option, since in my experience, summing flat arrays is (strangely) faster than counting. This code seems faster:

```py
df.isnull().values.any()
```

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import perfplot


def setup(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(n))
    df[df > 0.9] = np.nan
    return df


def isnull_any(df):
    return df.isnull().any()


def isnull_values_sum(df):
    return df.isnull().values.sum() > 0


def isnull_sum(df):
    return df.isnull().sum() > 0


def isnull_values_any(df):
    return df.isnull().values.any()


perfplot.save(
    "out.png",
    setup=setup,
    kernels=[isnull_any, isnull_values_sum, isnull_sum, isnull_values_any],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(25)],
)
```

`df.isnull().sum().sum()` is a bit slower, but of course, has additional information -- the number of `NaNs`.

Comment: Thank you for the time benchmarks. It's surprising that `pandas` doesn't have a built in function for this. It's true from @JGreenwell's post that `df.describe()` can do this, but no direct function.

Comment: I just timed `df.describe()` (without finding `NaN`s). With a 1000 x 1000 array, a single call takes 1.15 seconds.

Comment: :1, Also, `df.isnull().values.sum()` is a bit faster than `df.isnull().values.flatten().sum()`

Comment: Ah, good catch @JohnGalt -- I'll change my solution to remove the `.flatten()` for postering. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't try `df.isnull().values.any()`, for me it is faster than the others.

Comment: I agree with @CK1. For me `df.isnull().values.any()` is twice as fast (0.7 ms) than `df.isnull().values.sum()` (1.4 ms)

Comment: `np.isnan(df.values).any()` works a bit faster, but it doesn't work for object dtype

Comment: `df.shape[1] - df.dropna(axis = 1).shape[1]` would quickly confirm how many columns have null values in entire dataframe

Comment: This also works with a single column, e.g., `df['col1'].isnull().values.any()`

Comment: I'm surprised that no one has mentioned that `isnull_any`'s implementation is wrong. It is returning a Series object, not boolean. One has to return `df.isnull().any().any()` instead of `df.isnull().any()` to get a boolean.

Answer (score 237):

You have a couple of options.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,6))
# Make a few areas have NaN values
df.iloc[1:3,1] = np.nan
df.iloc[5,3] = np.nan
df.iloc[7:9,5] = np.nan
```

Now the data frame looks something like this:

```
          0         1         2         3         4         5
0  0.520113  0.884000  1.260966 -0.236597  0.312972 -0.196281
1 -0.837552       NaN  0.143017  0.862355  0.346550  0.842952
2 -0.452595       NaN -0.420790  0.456215  1.203459  0.527425
3  0.317503 -0.917042  1.780938 -1.584102  0.432745  0.389797
4 -0.722852  1.704820 -0.113821 -1.466458  0.083002  0.011722
5 -0.622851 -0.251935 -1.498837       NaN  1.098323  0.273814
6  0.329585  0.075312 -0.690209 -3.807924  0.489317 -0.841368
7 -1.123433 -1.187496  1.868894 -2.046456 -0.949718       NaN
8  1.133880 -0.110447  0.050385 -1.158387  0.188222       NaN
9 -0.513741  1.196259  0.704537  0.982395 -0.585040 -1.693810
```

- **Option 1**: `df.isnull().any().any()` - This returns a boolean value

You know of the `isnull()` which would return a dataframe like this:

```
       0      1      2      3      4      5
0  False  False  False  False  False  False
1  False   True  False  False  False  False
2  False   True  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False  False  False
4  False  False  False  False  False  False
5  False  False  False   True  False  False
6  False  False  False  False  False  False
7  False  False  False  False  False   True
8  False  False  False  False  False   True
9  False  False  False  False  False  False
```

If you make it `df.isnull().any()`, you can find just the columns that have `NaN` values:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool
```

One more `.any()` will tell you if any of the above are `True`

```
> df.isnull().any().any()
True
```

- **Option 2**: `df.isnull().sum().sum()` - This returns an integer of the total number of `NaN` values:

This operates the same way as the `.any().any()` does, by first giving a summation of the number of `NaN` values in a column, then the summation of those values:

```
df.isnull().sum()
0    0
1    2
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    2
dtype: int64
```

Finally, to get the total number of NaN values in the DataFrame:

```
df.isnull().sum().sum()
5
```

Comment: Why not using `.any(axis=None)` instead of `.any().any()`?

Answer (score 113):

To find out which rows have NaNs in a specific column:

```
nan_rows = df[df['name column'].isnull()]
```

Comment: To find out which rows do not have NaNs in a specific column: `non_nan_rows = df[df['name column'].notnull()]`.

Comment: that's the one i needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 67):

If you need to know how many rows there are with "one or more `NaN`s":

```
df.isnull().T.any().T.sum()
```

Or if you need to pull out these rows and examine them:

```
nan_rows = df[df.isnull().T.any()]
```

Comment: what is `T`  here  ?

Comment: alias for `.transpose()`

Answer (score 59):

`df.isnull().any().any()` should do it.

Answer (score 35):

## Super Simple Syntax: `df.isna().any(axis=None)`

[Starting from v0.23.2](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/whatsnew.html#logical-reductions-over-entire-dataframe), you can use [`DataFrame.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) + [`DataFrame.any(axis=None)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) where `axis=None` specifies logical reduction over the entire DataFrame.

```
# Setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, np.nan], 'B' : [np.nan, 4, 5]})
df
     A    B
0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  4.0
2  NaN  5.0
```

```
df.isna()

       A      B
0  False   True
1  False  False
2   True  False

df.isna().any(axis=None)
# True
```

---

## Useful Alternatives

**[`numpy.isnan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html)**
Another performant option if you're running older versions of pandas.

```
np.isnan(df.values)

array([[False,  True],
       [False, False],
       [ True, False]])

np.isnan(df.values).any()
# True
```

Alternatively, check the sum:

```
np.isnan(df.values).sum()
# 2

np.isnan(df.values).sum() > 0
# True
```

**[`Series.hasnans`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.hasnans.html#pandas-series-hasnans)**
You can also iteratively call `Series.hasnans`. For example, to check if a single column has NaNs,

```
df['A'].hasnans
# True
```

And to check if *any* column has NaNs, you can use a comprehension with `any` (which is a short-circuiting operation).

```
any(df[c].hasnans for c in df)
# True
```

This is actually *very* fast.

Comment: This might not be the fastest option but it is the most readable one in 2022 :)

Answer (score 24):

Adding to Hobs brilliant answer, I am very new to Python and Pandas so please point out if I am wrong.

To find out which rows have NaNs:

```
nan_rows = df[df.isnull().any(1)]
```

would perform the same operation without the need for transposing by specifying the axis of any() as 1 to check if 'True' is present in rows.

Comment: This gets rid of **two** transposes! Love your concise `any(axis=1)` simplification.

Answer (score 21):

let `df` be the name of the Pandas DataFrame and any value that is `numpy.nan` is a null value.

1. If you want to see which columns has nulls and which do not(just True and False)

   ```
   df.isnull().any()
   ```
2. If you want to see only the columns that has nulls

   ```
   df.loc[:, df.isnull().any()].columns
   ```
3. If you want to see the count of nulls in every column

   ```
   df.isna().sum()
   ```
4. If you want to see the percentage of nulls in every column

   ```
   df.isna().sum()/(len(df))*100
   ```
5. If you want to see the percentage of nulls in columns only with nulls:

```
df.loc[:,list(df.loc[:,df.isnull().any()].columns)].isnull().sum()/(len(df))*100
```

EDIT 1:

If you want to see where your data is missing visually:

```
import missingno
missingdata_df = df.columns[df.isnull().any()].tolist()
missingno.matrix(df[missingdata_df])
```

Comment: _If you want to see the count of nulls in every column..._ That seems insane, why not just do `df.isna().sum()` ?

Answer (score 11):

Since none have mentioned, there is just another variable called `hasnans`.

`df[i].hasnans` will output to `True` if one or more of the values in the pandas Series is NaN, `False` if not. Note that its not a function.

pandas version '0.19.2' and '0.20.2'

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Pandas Series have this attribute but DataFrames do not. If `df = DataFrame([1,None], columns=['foo'])`, then `df.hasnans` will throw an `AttributeError`, but `df.foo.hasnans` will return `True`.

Answer (score 8):

Since `pandas` has to find this out for `DataFrame.dropna()`, I took a look to see how they implement it and discovered that they made use of `DataFrame.count()`, which counts all non-null values in the `DataFrame`. Cf. [pandas source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L3013). I haven't benchmarked this technique, but I figure the authors of the library are likely to have made a wise choice for how to do it.

Answer (score 8):

I've been using the following and type casting it to a string and checking for the nan value

```
   (str(df.at[index, 'column']) == 'nan')
```

This allows me to check specific value in a series and not just return if this is contained somewhere within the series.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using this over `pandas.isna()` ?

Comment: This allows checking a single field.

Answer (score 8):

try the following

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

or

```
df.isna().values.any()
```

Answer (score 7):

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

This will give you count of all NaN values present in the respective coloums of the DataFrame.

Comment: No, that will give you a Series which maps column names to their respective number of NA values.

Comment: Corrected, my fault :p

Answer (score 5):

Just using
[math.isnan(x)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isnan), Return True if x is a NaN (not a number), and False otherwise.

Comment: I don't think `math.isnan(x)` is going to work when `x` is a DataFrame. You get a TypeError instead.

Comment: Why would you use this over any of the alternatives?

Answer (score 4):

Here is another interesting way of finding null and replacing with a calculated value

```
    #Creating the DataFrame

    testdf = pd.DataFrame({'Tenure':[1,2,3,4,5],'Monthly':[10,20,30,40,50],'Yearly':[10,40,np.nan,np.nan,250]})
    >>> testdf2
       Monthly  Tenure  Yearly
    0       10       1    10.0
    1       20       2    40.0
    2       30       3     NaN
    3       40       4     NaN
    4       50       5   250.0

    #Identifying the rows with empty columns
    nan_rows = testdf2[testdf2['Yearly'].isnull()]
    >>> nan_rows
       Monthly  Tenure  Yearly
    2       30       3     NaN
    3       40       4     NaN

    #Getting the rows# into a list
    >>> index = list(nan_rows.index)
    >>> index
    [2, 3]

    # Replacing null values with calculated value
    >>> for i in index:
        testdf2['Yearly'][i] = testdf2['Monthly'][i] * testdf2['Tenure'][i]
    >>> testdf2
       Monthly  Tenure  Yearly
    0       10       1    10.0
    1       20       2    40.0
    2       30       3    90.0
    3       40       4   160.0
    4       50       5   250.0
```

Answer (score 4):

We can see the null values present in the dataset by generating heatmap using seaborn module[heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDmlz.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
dataset=pd.read_csv('train.csv')
sns.heatmap(dataset.isnull(),cbar=False)
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend to use values attribute as evaluation on array is much faster.

```py
arr = np.random.randn(100, 100)
arr[40, 40] = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

%timeit np.isnan(df.values).any()  # 7.56 µs
%timeit np.isnan(df).any()         # 627 µs
%timeit df.isna().any(axis=None)   # 572 µs
```

Result:

```
7.56 µs ± 447 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
627 µs ± 40.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
572 µs ± 15.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Note: You need to run `%timeit` in Jupyter notebook to work

Answer (score 3):

The best would be to use:

```
df.isna().any().any()
```

Here is [why](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0409521665bd436a10aea7e06336066bf07ff057/pandas/core/dtypes/missing.py#L109). So `isna()` is used to define `isnull()`, but both of these are identical of course.

This is even faster than the accepted answer and covers all 2D panda arrays.

Answer (score 3):

To do this we can use the statement `df.isna().any()` . This will check all of our columns and return `True` if there are any missing values or `NaN`s, or `False` if there are no missing values.

Answer (score 3):

This will only include columns with at least 1 null/na value.

```
 df.isnull().sum()[df.isnull().sum()>0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `.info()` on the `DF` such as :

`df.info(null_counts=True)` which returns the number of non_null rows in a columns such as:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3276314 entries, 0 to 3276313
Data columns (total 10 columns):
n_matches                          3276314 non-null int64
avg_pic_distance                   3276314 non-null float64
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import missingno as msno
msno.matrix(df)  # just to visualize. no missing value.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to `dropna` and check if the lengths are equivalent:

```
>>> len(df.dropna()) != len(df)
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.apply(axis=0, func=lambda x : any(pd.isnull(x)))
```

Will check for each column if it contains Nan or not.

Comment: Why use this over any of the builtin solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You could not only check if any 'NaN' exist but also get the percentage of 'NaN's in each column using the following,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5],'col2':[6,np.nan,8,9,10]})  
df  

   col1 col2  
0   1   6.0  
1   2   NaN  
2   3   8.0  
3   4   9.0  
4   5   10.0  


df.isnull().sum()/len(df)  
col1    0.0  
col2    0.2  
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

[Bar representation for missing values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcZZr.png)

```
import missingno
missingno.bar(df)# will give you exact no of values and values missing
```

Answer (score 0):

This is code makes your life easy

```
import sidetable

df.stb.missing()
```

Check this out : https://github.com/chris1610/sidetable

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given the following dataframe:

```
     A  B    C
0  1.0  a  NaN
1  2.0  b  4.0
2  NaN  c  5.0
```

1. Check if there are any NaN values:

   ```py
   df.isna().any(axis=None)              # True
   df.isna().to_numpy().any()            # True
   df.ne(df).any(axis=None)              # True
   (df!=df).any(axis=None)               # True
   df.eval("A!=A or B!=B or C!=C").any() # True
   ```
2. Column labels with NaN values:

   ```py
   df.isna().any().pipe(lambda x: x.index[x])        

   Index(['A', 'C'], dtype='object')
   ```
3. Index labels with NaN values:

   ```py
   df.isna().any(axis=1).pipe(lambda x: x.index[x])

   Index([0, 2], dtype='int64')
   ```
4. Columns with NaN values:

   ```py
   df.loc[:, df.isna().any()]

        A    C
   0  1.0  NaN
   1  2.0  4.0
   2  NaN  5.0
   ```
5. Rows with NaN values:

   ```py
   df[df.isna().any(axis=1)]

        A  B    C
   0  1.0  a  NaN
   2  NaN  c  5.0
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the type of data you're dealing with, you could also just get the value counts of each column while performing your EDA by setting dropna to False.

```
for col in df:
   print df[col].value_counts(dropna=False)
```

Works well for categorical variables, not so much when you have many unique values.

Comment: I think this is inefficient. Built-in functions of pandas are more neat/terse. Avoids cluttering of the ipython notebook.