# Python Pandas- Select rows where multiple columns are null

Tags: python, pandas, null

I want to select rows which have multiple columns(4 in the following example) as null values. I have used the following code:

```
data[(data['relevent_experience'].isnull())&data['education_level'].isnull())&data['major_disciplne'].isnull())&data['relevent_experience'].isnull())]
```

This is a very complicated code. Is there a cleaner way to do the same thing?

Comment: Use marked duplicate. Instead of `any` you can use `all`.

Comment: separate your statements in multiple row.s

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the above mentioned question. I want to only those rows with null values in those specific columns. I don't care about other columns, but the above mentioned 4 columns should have null values.

Comment: df_no_nan = df.dropna(subset=['Col1','Col2, 'Col3'], how='any')

Comment: check the accepted answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370839/better-way-to-drop-nan-rows-in-pandas

Comment: data[data.loc[:,'column1', 'column2',.., 'columnn'].isna().apply(lambda x: all(x), axis=1)]