# Pandas to_csv but remove NaNs on individual cell level without dropping full row or column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv, missing-data

I have a dataframe of comments from a survey. I want to export the dataframe as a csv file and remove the NaNs without dropping any rows or columns (unless an entire row is NaN, for instance). Here is a sample of the dataframe:

[image]

I don't care about maintaining the index so I'm, fine with just dropping individual cells with NaNs and shifting those column's rows up instead of dropping entire rows, so I'd just have a nice compressed output csv file without any empty cells.

Comment: It's not a sample of your dataframe, it's an image. Try: `df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=1)` as the first part of your code.

Comment: What are you replacing `NaN` with on the individual cells?

Comment: I just want those cells to disappear without removing the entire row @MarceloPaco

Comment: Does this answer your question? [better way to drop nan rows in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370839/better-way-to-drop-nan-rows-in-pandas)

Comment: you're taking about exporting to csv. do they still show up as `NaN` in the exported csv because it shouldn't. other's have answered on how to drop rows containing all the NaNs

Comment: It doesn't show up as NaN, just empty cells. I'd like the empty cells to disappear on a cell-by-cell basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove entire rows with all `NaN` you can use [`dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = df.dropna(how='all')
```

To remove `NaN` on the individual cell level in the data frame you can use [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) by setting it to an empty string:

```
df = df.fillna("")
```

Comment: Thanks. `df.dropna(how = 'all')` was good enough. Didn't exactly accomplish my goal of dropping individual cells with NaN but it was just fine for what I needed.