# Need of additional Transpose method

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

While looking for an answer of how to check NaN values, I found this stack overflow post.

[How to check if any value is NaN in a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530232/how-to-check-if-any-value-is-nan-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

I used the answer by hobs. But I am getting exactly same results with or without the last transpose method.

```
nan_rows = df[df.isnull().T.any().T]

nan_rows = df[df.isnull().T.any()]
```

Exactly the same rows return for both the statements.
Is there any specific reason that the answer mentioned has additional T ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think we need adding a `T` at the end , since `df.isnull().T.any()` give out a `pd.Series`

```
df.isnull().T.any()
Out[33]: 
0    False
1     True
2     True
dtype: bool
df.isnull().T.any().T
Out[34]: 
0    False
1     True
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Also why not

```
df.isnull().any(axis = 1)
Out[37]: 
0    False
1     True
2     True
dtype: bool
```