# Python-pandas, np.nan

Tags: python, pandas, nan

Could you guys please help me explain the code below:

Why a `nan` is not `np.nan`?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df.iloc[31464]['SalesPersonID']
[out]:
nan

df.iloc[31464]['SalesPersonID'] is np.nan
[out]:
False
```

Thank you, all.

Comment: Use .isnan() instead to compare NaN values

Comment: [How to check if any value is NaN in a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530232/)

Comment: Related: [Why in numpy `nan == nan` is False while `nan in [nan]` is True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320022/why-in-numpy-nan-nan-is-false-while-nan-in-nan-is-true)

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you, all.

Answer (score 7):

`np.nan` is a special value in numpy. Read [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/misc.html) for more information on it.

The link above mentions the following code snippet:

```
>>> np.nan == np.nan  # is always False! Use special numpy functions instead.
```

Also, `type(df.iloc[31464]['SalesPersonID'])` is `np.float64`.

Answer (score 3):

use `np.isnan(np.nan)` which gives **True** or

`np.isnan(df.iloc[31464]['SalesPersonID'])` which gives **True**

Comment: Great help! Thanks, all.

Comment: mark an answer as approved. whichever has helped you.