# How to show indexes with `NaN` values ​for each column in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I'll explain on example.

I have this data:

```
id    day   week
1     10    3
2     NaN   4
NaN   NaN   5
```

And I need this output:

```
id     [2]
day    [1, 2]
week   False (or smth like this)
```

Output shows indexes with `NaN` values ​​for each column.

I have written code for this, but I don't like it:

```
 index_nan = []
 for col in data.columns:
        if data[col].isnull().sum()==0:
            index_nan.append('False')
        else:
            index_nan.append(str(data[data[col].isna()].index.to_numpy()))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if any value is NaN in a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530232/how-to-check-if-any-value-is-nan-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2):

use `isna`

try this,

```
df=df.isna()
for col in df.columns.values:
    print(col, df.index[df[col]].tolist())
```

O/P:

```
id [2]
day [1, 2]
week []
```