# How to check if any value is NaN(of type numpy.float64) in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I couldn't find an answer from suggested question
[Suggested Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530232/how-to-check-if-any-value-is-nan-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

I'm trying to check if the value is NaN(of type `numpy.float64`).

Sample Df:

```
 df

        amt
 0      50.0
 1      NaN
 2      25.0
```

Type is `type(df['due amount'][1])` is numpy.float64.

I'm trying to check if this value is NaN or not.

```
  tnx_final['due amount'][1] == np.nan   #This won't work as type is  numpy.float64
```

What should be the numpy equivalent for the above code? Is there a way to find without changing column type to `str` ?

Comment: Check `tnx_final['due amount'].isna()`

Comment: I need to check a particular row like this `tnx_final['due amount'][1] == np.nan`

Comment: Sorry, it is wrong link. Added correct.

Comment: Thanks but that link also didn't solve the question. 
`tnx_final['due amount'][1] == np.nan`. Any numpy.float64 equivalent to np.nan?

Comment: Any numpy.float64 equivalent to np.nan? - Not exist.

Comment: `df.loc[df['amt'] == np.nan,'amt'] = df['another_column_value']`. So for this case is there a way to check `== np.nan` ?

Comment: If need test misisng values in numpy, check second code in accepted answer, use `np.isnan(tnx_final['due amount'][1])`

Comment: Yes, then need `df.loc[df['amt'].isnan(),'amt'] = df['another_column_value']`

Comment: Or `df['amt'] = df['amt'].fillna(df['another_column_value'])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224724/discussion-between-zanthoxylum-piperitum-and-jezrael).