# How to get a single boolean value as the output

Tags: pandas, dataframe, boolean

I have this data frame where I have to check if the data has any Nan values. I have used the code `'df.isnull().any()'`, But this gives me an output where it shows a single boolean value for each of the columns whereas I need the output to be a single boolean value for the whole data frame.

Comment: `df.isnull().any(axis=1)`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29530303/9840637

Comment: This gives me an output where it shows a boolean value for each of the rows in the dataframe. I need the output to be a singe true or false .That is if the whole data frame has any missing value if yes then true if no then false .