# Counting the number of missing/NaN in each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, nan

I've got a dataset with a big number of rows. Some of the values are NaN, like this:

```
In [91]: df
Out[91]:
 1    3      1      1      1
 1    3      1      1      1
 2    3      1      1      1
 1    1    NaN    NaN    NaN
 1    3      1      1      1
 1    1      1      1      1
```

And I want to count the number of NaN values in each row, it would be like this:

```
In [91]: list = <somecode with df>
In [92]: list
    Out[91]:
     [0,
      0,
      0,
      3,
      0,
      0]
```

What is the best and fastest way to do it?

Comment: Similar question for columns: [How do I get a summary count of missing/NaN data by column in 'pandas'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257527/how-do-i-get-a-summary-of-the-counts-of-missing-data-in-pandas)

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You could first find if element is `NaN` or not by `isnull()` and then take row-wise `sum(axis=1)`

```
In [195]: df.isnull().sum(axis=1)
Out[195]:
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    3
4    0
5    0
dtype: int64
```

And, if you want the output as list, you can

```
In [196]: df.isnull().sum(axis=1).tolist()
Out[196]: [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0]
```

---

Or use `count` like

```
In [130]: df.shape[1] - df.count(axis=1)
Out[130]:
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    3
4    0
5    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

To count NaNs in specific rows, use

```py
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
df['number_of_NaNs'] = df[cols].isna().sum(1)
```

or index the columns by position, e.g. count NaNs in the first 4 columns:

```py
df['number_of_NaNs'] = df.iloc[:, :4].isna().sum(1)
```