# Iterate through rows in Dataframe using a function and count the non NA values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, series

My Dataframe: billboard_2
[image]

I need to count the number of weeks a song is on billboards by using an apply function and a simple python function. But apparently, I am not able to do so.

I managed to do it via the lambda function but I am supposed to use apply function. The output I am getting lambda function is exactly what I need using the normal function.

```
WeeklyRating = billboard_2.apply(lambda x : x.count()-1, axis=1)

WeeklyRating
```

Output using lambda function
[image]

I tried converting that lambda function to a normal function but each time I am getting some error.
Following is what I tried and I got an error saying - 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'.

```
def bill_week(val):
    for i, row in val.iterrows():
        return(row.count()-1)

billboard_2.apply(bill_week)
```

I guess what I am asking is how do I convert that lambda function to a normal function.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please [don't post images of code/data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) instead add them in text format so that we could be able to copy these while trying to answer your question. Please take some time to read [How to ask good pandas questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know good sir, I will read through the post and make sure I ask a formatted question next time.

Comment: There is no need to use `apply` or `iterrows` here, you can simply count the `non-NaN` values using a vectorized function. Please check `billboard_2.drop('track', axis=1).count(axis=1)`

Comment: I think this will be helpul: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059260/python-pandas-counting-the-number-of-missing-nan-in-each-row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count(axis=1)` let alone gives no. of non-na values in a row

```
billboard_2.count(axis=1)
```

If you want to use `.apply`

```
def count_non_na(x):
    return x.isna().sum()

billboard_2.apply(count_non_na, axis=1)
```

In combination with `lambda`

```
billboard_2.apply(lambda x: x.isna().sum(), axis=1)
```