# Taking the column names from the first row that has less than x Nan's

Tags: python, pandas

I have data as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

url_cities="https://population.un.org/wup/Download/Files/WUP2018-F12-Cities_Over_300K.xls"
df_cities = pd.read_excel(url_cities)
print(df_cities.iloc[0:20,])
```

The column names can be found in row 15, but I would like this row number to be automatically determined. I thought the best way would be to take the first row for which the values are non-Nan for less than 10 items.

I combined [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059260/python-pandas-counting-the-number-of-missing-nan-in-each-row), to find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361426/get-the-first-item-from-an-iterable-that-matches-a-condition/2364277#2364277) to do the following:

```
amount_Nan = df_cities.shape[1] - df_cities.count(axis=1)
# OR df.isnull().sum(axis=1).tolist()

print(amount_Nan)
col_names_index = next(i for i in amount_Nan if i < 3)
print(col_names_index)

df_cities.columns = df_cities.iloc[col_names_index]
```

The problem is that `col_names_index` keeps returning `0`, while it should be `15`. I think it is because `amount_Nan` returns rows and columns because of which `next(i for i in amount_Nan if i < 3)` works differently than expected.

The thing is that I do not really understand why. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can get first index of non missing value per second column by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) and [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html), set columns names by this row and filter out values before this row by index:

```
i = df_cities.iloc[:, 1].notna().idxmax()
              
df_cities.columns = df_cities.iloc[i].tolist()
df_cities = df_cities.iloc[i+1:]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I believe `df_cities = df_cities.iloc[i:]` should maybe be `df_cities = df_cities.iloc[i+1:]` right?

Comment: @Tom - You are right, just tested.